# The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to submit app on AppStore, My app is having swift speech SDK library, and project is in Obj C, Whenever I am trying to upload my build, I am getting this error,Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.
 **Doing Embedded Content Contains Swift Code -> YES in target setting, not working.**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Incase your project is having swift classes /library:, Please ensure below settings are as follows:

Project/Target settings -> build Settings

```
1. Defines Module -> YES
2. Always embed Swift Standard libraries -> YES
```

It solved my problem.

Comment: Solve my problem. Have tried others solution but only this works.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore. Setting method=app-store in exportOptions.plist does produce the SwiftSupport directory, but requires a distribution certificate and provisioning profile(s). This may be an issue for CI builds that make developer-signed .ipas.

Comment: didn't help me unf, with my flutter project 

Answer (score 20):

In my case was because I was using an Adhoc provisioning profile instead of a production one when I was trying to deploy to the App Store Connect.

Answer (score 0):

Once you Archive the project and right-click the Archive, click "show in finder", again right-click the .xcarchive, click "show in finder". Check whether the SwiftSupport is listed. If not:

- First check Project/Target/Build Settings:

1. Defines Module -> YES
2. Always embed Swift Standard libraries -> YES

- Then try to build with the latest Xcode.
- If the build upload via pipeline shows the "Invalid Swift Support" error, try with the Transporter application too, to confirm the issue is not due to any pipeline setting/command.

If you still can't see SwiftSupport or with SwiftSupport if you are facing the same "Invalid Swift Support" error, the last try is to use an App Store profile instead of an Adhoc profile. With the App Store profile, the issue was resolved for me.