# Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is empty

Tags: swift, react-native, watchkit, testflight, watchos

My build is successfully uploaded but Not shown on testflight due to below issue sent by apple.
App detail : I am having iPhone app in React Native and watchOS app in swift langauge.
Xcode version : 11.3

Issue reported by apple -

> ITMS-XXXX: Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is empty.
> Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and
> resubmit it.

I searched and tried lot of things but nothing work. Also tried below link

1. [The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42061953/the-swiftsupport-folder-is-missing-rebuild-your-app-using-the-current-public-g)
2. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/125902
3. "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" set to Yes

**Updated Answer of my query** :
I have resolved the issue by adding the required framework in watchOS folder of Swift Support. May be its Xcode issue which is creating empty folder for my watchOS. Followed below steps

> 1. Copy watchOS lib swift file from this path "‎⁨ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ToolChains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/⁨watchos⁩"
>    Or You can also get framework from your previous watch build which is
>    successfully uploaded
> 2. Paste the copied library in below location
>
> 2.1 Create Archive of your app -> Right click on selected build and select show in finder -> show package content -> Swiftsupport ->
> watchOS/"Paste here"
>
> 2.2 Paste those frame in framework folder also by following the below path
> Right click on selected build and select show in finder -> show package content -> Products ->
> Applications -> right click on ipa file -> show package
> content->Watch->Right click on your watch app -> show package content
> -> Frameworks/"Paste here"
>
> 3. Set "Always embedded swift standard libraries" to yes in builsetting of you main app target and watchkitapp (Not in extension)
>
> Optional step
>
> if your SwiftSupport->iPhoneOS folder is also empty then
> just create new swift file to your objective c code it will ask for
> bridge rest it will do for all required things (No need to connect
> this file with any objective c just add it to project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by setting the deployment target same for all extensions added in project.

Initially RN project having 11.0 deployment target and newly added watch having latest one 13.0 so swift folder is not created automatically. after modifying all to 12.0, it works automatically without doing any manual step.

Answer (score 6):

My work-around for this issue is:

1. in the Xcode -> Organizer window, after you create an archive, right-click on your new
   archive
2. press "Show in Finder"
3. right click on the archive in Finder
4. press "Show Package Contents"
5. delete the 'SwiftSupport' folder

Now you can submit without getting that error.

I encountered this issue on a React Native project.

I tried a lot of the most popular solutions e.g. editing Build Settings and none of those worked for me.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. The accepted solution of setting the deployment targets to the same number didn't. Any idea about whether Apple reviewers mind when you submit your app for being available in stores?

Answer (score 3):

This is a very annoying issue and happens whenever you used third-party tools to make the application rather than Xcode. To fix this issue you must be calm first and need to follow these steps, I encountered in the same situation and after that, I wrote myself some scripts to solve that issue.

1. Get Your .app file from XCode.
2. identify third party SDK that is using swift.
3. Create A folder with your app name.
4. Within that folder create two folders with the name "Payload" and "SwifSupport"
5. Put your .app file inside Payload
6. Create another "iphonesos" folder under "SwiftSupport"
7. copies swift .dylib files to that folder. make sure codesign of that swift .dylib should not be with your's certificate, just copy from the following path.
   "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ToolChains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift"
8. Make sure your third party libs should be signed with your own certificate.
9. After that just make .ipa and upload on AppStore it should work. 
   Cheers if you face issues you can write to me here. mshauket.developer@gmail.com

Comment: thanks for explaining. Currently I am facing the same problem and there is no SwiftSuport folder in the .app/Frameworks.  I created SwiftSupport/iphoneos inside .app and copied swift dylib files from the path that you mentioned. But they are 190 MB and that is not desired. Do I need to copy all of the swift dylibs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to copy all the .dylib files, can you check which framework using swift files? just go trhough that framework and see which .dylib they are using. same .dylib you need to put in swiftsupport

Comment: make sure code sign of swiftsupport folder and frameworkd folder should be diff.

Comment: found my problem. It looks like third party dylib files are not allowed inside Frameworks and they need to be changed to .framework and then copied inside Frameworks. So that was the reason that I got this error missing SwiftSupport. Thank you anyway @ShauketSheikh

Comment: @peco , are you able to get that swift folder files auto generated by Xcode instead of empty . if yes the can you elaborate more. how you are able to do get that ?

Comment: I did not get SwiftSupport folder, but I got Swift dylib libraries inside Frameworks. In my case I was not using swift and the error was confusing. So I tried to get Swift dylibs files by adding empty Swift file in my Objective-C app so that missing swift dylibs are automatically coppied. As I mentioned before I did not get SwiftSupport folder and I still got the error Missing Swift Support. Then I realized that problem was third party dylibs inside Frameworks

Comment: if your project does not give you swiftsupport folder, we can make call on zoom to discuss and I can help you to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the issue in **React Native project** (0.66.4) after bumping **iOS Deployment Target** from **11.0** to **13.0** in Xcode (12.5). The issue also stayed with the latest Xcode 13.2.1. Our project doesn't use Swift, our own native code is all written in Objective-C, but we use some libraries that are implemented in Swift.

I have spent some days on it and tried every single solution I could find. The solution from [@RC Whim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62294694/5569272) worked for me. However, we have a distributed development team of several people, configured CI/CD and automated process. We could not rely on manual actions to remove the folder on every build.

I have created and added **a Post-action to Archive option** of our app scheme in Xcode to automate the process of removing the folder.

Here is the code:

```sh
ARCHIVES_PATH="/Users/$USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives"
ARCHIVE_DIR=

for file in "$ARCHIVES_PATH"/* ; do
    [[ -L $file || ! -d $file ]] && continue
    [[ -z $ARCHIVE_DIR || $file -nt $ARCHIVE_DIR ]] && ARCHIVE_DIR=$file
done

if [ ! -d "${ARCHIVE_DIR}" ]; then
    echo "No archive directory found!"
    exit 1
fi

ARCHIVE=$(ls -t ${ARCHIVE_DIR} | head -n 1)

XCARCHIVE_PATH="${ARCHIVE_DIR}/${ARCHIVE}"
# APP="${XCARCHIVE_PATH}/Products/Applications/moonlightreact.app"

SWIFT_SUPPORT_DIR="${XCARCHIVE_PATH}/SwiftSupport"

if find "${SWIFT_SUPPORT_DIR}/iphoneos" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | read; then
   echo "SwiftSupport folder is not empty."
   exit 1
fi

rm -r "${SWIFT_SUPPORT_DIR}"

if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    echo "rm command failed."
else
    echo "SwiftSupport folder was removed."
fi
```

Here is how it looks:

[image: Post-actions in Archive option in Xcode]