# ITMS-90424: Invalid Swift Support

Tags: app-store-connect, appstore-approval, xcode11

I am trying to upload my app to the app store. I can archive my app and successfully upload to App Store Connect, however, it keeps getting rejected with the following error message:

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "Retainer Tracker" 1.0 >>(8). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
>
> ITMS-90424: Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is empty. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

I've tried a bunch of diffrent fixes I've found online but still can't get it to work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The basic reason is your application using swift and your swiftsupport folder is empty. Let's move in detail

1. If your application using Xcode to make .ipa file and there is no third-party IDE involve to create Xcode project, you can fix this issue by upgrading your Xcode
2. If you are using some other IDE to make the Xcode project then please follow that link. I already give the answer to this question. [Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59728413/invalid-swift-support-the-swiftsupport-folder-is-empty/59833694#59833694)

Comment: I'm using xcode and I am using the latest version, any other possible ideas?

Comment: my question is again, did you created application using xcode or you used third party IDE to generate xcode project?

Comment: Then swift support folders issue should not happen, just give a try to see swift support symbol is enabled in your project setting?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred right after I added a specific Swift Library

Doing the following fixed the issue in my case

Go to Targets > YourApp > Build Settings

Under Packaging:

```
Defines Module: Yes
```

Under Assets:

```
Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries: Yes
```

Comment: not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

> ITMS-90426: Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.

For us, our CICD pipeline was using an Ad-Hoc Provisioning Profile to distribute the `ipa` build to Testflight/AppStore.

We fixed this by using an App-Store Provisioning Profile instead.