# SwiftSupport folder is missing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the usual problem :

ITMS-90424: Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is empty. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.

I have tried this answer but the Xcode version has changed and these attributes don't exist anymore :
[The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42061953/the-swiftsupport-folder-is-missing-rebuild-your-app-using-the-current-public-g)

No solutions for october 2020 and i have already writen to the Apple Support which doesn't know how to help...

I have also tried to set the **Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries** to YES on my workspace, inside the Project/targets -> Build Settings -> Build Options.

My tools :

- Xcode version : 12.0.1
- Swift version : 5
- I have Swift files
- Using Pods (Cocoapods) for libraries dependencies

When i create a new archive, i am able to **Show package content** and find a **SwiftSupport** folder which contains another empty folder **iphoneos**.

I have also tried to delete it before upload despite the message (based on Apple developper forum answers) without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally managed to do it by deleting the SwiftSupport manually folder from the archive package content and re-validating the application before distribution.

I have also deleted derived data using the DevCleaner application but i don't know if that helped in this case.