# Error message when using xcframework: ITMS-90426: Invalid Swift Support

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I use this package in my app:

https://github.com/liamnichols/_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser

which contains an xcframework: **_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.xcframework** which contains **dylib** files

All is good with this package, my app works well in simulator and real device. But when I uploaded a version to the App Store Connect, I got this error message:

**ITMS-90426: Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.**

Is there a solution for that? I searched a lot with out any chance to solve it.

What I tried:

(1) I tried to add manually the SwiftSupport folder using the script here:

https://gist.github.com/adamzarn/6bb89d91ed4b8c3d3fb25363c221441f

(2) Then the error message is now:

**ITMS-90430: Invalid Swift Support - The file lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib doesn’t have a signing ID. Sign the file, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it.**

(3) Trying to signing the file using:

`codesign --force --timestamp --sign <name of certificate> <binary you want to sign>`

But I always get the same error message in (2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42061953/the-swiftsupport-folder-is-missing-rebuild-your-app-using-the-current-public-g)

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Unfortunately no.